# Can't make a variable retain its contents - darn it

Tags: javascript

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsvAF/7/), I can't make a link drop a tank from the sky. I just want to reuse all this code for each link I click and it all turns on this line:

```
$dropDiv.css({
```

Everything works if I hard code that to:

```
$('#holder1drop').css({
```

I tried this AND IT WORKS:

```
var $dropDiv = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "drop";
```

It grabs the link ID of `holder1`, prepends a `#` and appends 'drop' giving me `#holder1drop`. BEAUTIFUL.

But by the time the variable `$dropDiv` gets to the critical line - it doesn't, apparently, contain my carefully crafted contents any more.

And to make matters quite frustrating - `alert($dropDiv);` doesn't seem to work past the `var dh = lines` - inexplicably.

I just want a nice click and drop a tank or div script that works with multiple links. Is this a disgusting frankenstein bucket of death or am I on the right track?

Comment: The JSFiddle you posted works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is a simple one: `.css`works on jQuery objects. And a string is not a jQuery object.

Changing your original assigment to this should make your code work.

```
var $dropDiv = $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "drop");
```